# How to get the name, surname and email from dropbox object in python?

Tags: python, date, dropbox, account

i'm new in python and i try to get the name, surname and email from a dropbox object using the API v2 in python. I found this code but i get data that i don't need. How i can get only the datas previously named?

```
import dropbox
dbx = dropbox.Dropbox(<authentication-toke>) 
print(dbx.users_get_current_account())
```

Comment: Have you read the documentation?

Answer (score 0):

[The `users_get_current_account` method](https://dropbox-sdk-python.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/dropbox.html#dropbox.dropbox.Dropbox.users_get_current_account) returns a [`FullAccount` object](https://dropbox-sdk-python.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/users.html#dropbox.users.FullAccount). You can get the desired pieces of account information from that object, like this:

```
import dropbox

dbx = dropbox.Dropbox(<authentication-toke)

account = dbx.users_get_current_account()
print(account.name.given_name)
print(account.name.surname)
print(account.email)
```